Using NVL with TO_DATE and TO_CHAR functions resulting in ORA-01843 error
I have the below query that when I add the NVL function, I am getting an error

ORA-01843: not a valid month

I simply want to use the end date range as the current date (SYSDATE) if the parameter :Transaction_DateTO is NULL.
SELECT *
FROM MyTable TXN
WHERE 
    TXN.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN
       to_date(to_char(:Transaction_DateFROM,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')  
       AND 
       NVL(to_date(to_char(:Transaction_DateTO,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'), SYSDATE)  


If you are passing dates as bind variables then don't use TO_CHAR and TO_DATE on them, just use TRUNC (and add a day and use a non-inclusive upper-bound).
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  TRANSACTION_DATE >= TRUNC(:Transaction_DateFROM)
AND    TRANSACTION_DATE <  TRUNC(COALESCE(:Transaction_DateTO, SYSDATE)) + 1

If you want to use BETWEEN then add an interval literal:
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(:Transaction_DateFROM)
                            AND TRUNC(COALESCE(:Transaction_DateTO, SYSDATE))
                                  + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND


If you are passing strings then don't use TO_CHAR, just use TO_DATE:
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  TRANSACTION_DATE >= TO_DATE(:Transaction_DateFROM, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND    TRANSACTION_DATE <  COALESCE(
                             TO_DATE(:Transaction_DateTO, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                             TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                           ) + 1


